# How to create tikz `\node` command and retain access to it's properties from outside?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes

I'm trying to create latex command for specific node layout in tikz:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (anode) [lestyle, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]
    {
        \textbf{node A}
        \nodepart{second}description of A
    };
    \node (bnode) [lestyle, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, below=of anode]
    {
        \textbf{node B}
        \nodepart{second}description of B
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The layout of node internals will be more complex and I will have a lot of similar nodes. So, I want it to put common layout inside custom function. However, I want to allow properties to be added from outside of command, since nodes will differ in more properties than `below`.

I've created custom LaTex command for node.

```
\newcommand{\nodele}[2]{
    \node (mynodele) [lestyle, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]
    {
        \textbf{#1}
        \nodepart{second}#2
    }
}
```

and picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \nodele{node A}{description of A};
    \nodele{node B}{description of B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is: I can't set their names with `(name)` like in first example. Also, can't add custom properties (any, not only below)  to node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious choice is to make another input for the options

```
%    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\def\nodele[#1]#2#3{
    \node[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,#1]
    {
        \textbf{#2}
        \nodepart{second}#3
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \nodele[red,at={(3,1)},name=a]{node A}{description of A};
    \nodele[blue,below=of a]{node B}{description of B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, nice solution. Isn't that hard/complex as I expected, but is it possible to have name in brackets `(a)` instead of `name=a`?

Comment: @Miro Add another input if you want `[#1](#2)#3#4` :) But it would get also tedious to type these in if you have too many

Comment: I thought I understand little bit LaTeX. ...I've got now no idea how LaTeX works, but `\def\nodele(#1)[#2]#3#4` works perfectly ^_^